# SwiftUI crash: "precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 71”

Tags: swiftui

I have a very interesting crash, that only happens under very specific circumstances. I've already submitted a bug report to Apple, but maybe someone here has seen a similar crash, knows what's going on, and knows a workaround?

A minimal project showing the crash can be found at https://github.com/kevinrenskers/SwiftUICrash but I've also added the related code below. The project has 3 views: `RootView`, `DetailsView` and `ListView`. `RootView` embeds either the `DetailsView` or the `ListView`.

The crash happens when you press the trailing navigation bar button in `DetailsView` to switch back to the `ListView`. The app crashes with the error "precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 71”.

When you use the `Button` in the middle of the screen to switch back to the `ListView` however, the crash does NOT happen. And when you remove the `.resizable()` modifier from the background image, the crash also does NOT happen.

Also, if you change `Group` into `NavigationView` inside of `RootView`, the app doesn't crash. Sadly that's not an option for my real-world app though.

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class AppStore: ObservableObject {
  @Published var showingDetails = true
}

struct RootView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore

  var body: some View {
    Group {
      if store.showingDetails {
        DetailsView()
      } else {
        ListView()
      }
    }
  }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        GeometryReader { geo in
          Image("bg")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
        }

        Button("List") {
          self.store.showingDetails = false // <- this works fine
        }
        .padding(20)
        .background(Color.white)
      }
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Details"))
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: trailingNavigationBarItem)
    }
  }

  private var trailingNavigationBarItem: some View {
    Button("List") {
      self.store.showingDetails = false // <- this crashes the app!
    }
  }
}

struct ListView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Button("Load details") {
        self.store.showingDetails = true
      }
      .padding(20)
      .background(Color.white)
      .navigationBarTitle("List")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a promising workaround using a custom UIImageView via UIViewRepresentable, thus bypassing the resizable Image: https://github.com/kevinrenskers/SwiftUICrash/tree/workarounds/CustomImage. It solves the crash, but I can't get it to show full screen yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the group in `RootView` with a `@ViewBuilder` annotation:

```
struct RootView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore

  @ViewBuilder
  var body: some View {
    if store.showingDetails {
      DetailsView()
    } else {
      ListView()
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how reliable that is in general. I had mixed success inserting `@ViewBuilder` annotations in the past, but this seems to fix the issue with the nested `NavigationView`.

Comment: That is a brilliant fix, thanks! Sadly I kind of rely on the Group since I have `.onAppear` and `.sheet` modifiers on it, so I'll just keep using my custom UIImageView via UIViewRepresentable. But thanks again, this is definitely a tool I'll add to my arsenal. I'll award the points to you as well.

Comment: Actually, I can put all the logic in a computed property that returns a `some View` and is annotated with `@ViewBuilder`, and then have the modifiers attach to that. It's all good!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this workaround causes problems with iPad's split navigationview. See my other answer for a better workaround.

---

A workaround is to wrap the `RootView`'s `Group` in a `NavigationView`, with a hidden navigationbar (every nested view can potentially have its own navigationbar, not all of them have one):

```swift
struct RootView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Group {
        if store.showingDetails != nil {
          DetailsView(bg: store.showingDetails!)
        } else {
          ListView()
        }
      }
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
      .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
  }
}
```

The crash is still very very weird though.

Comment: Sadly this workaround is no longer a good one once I started to test the app on the iPad. That top level NavigationView is really messing with the split view navigation style that you want on iPad. Using a TabView solves the crash, but as you can't hide the tabbar, not a valid workaround for me.
Another fun fact: if you first rotate the iPad, that also prevents the crash from happening. It's all too damn weird.

Comment: Check https://github.com/kevinrenskers/SwiftUICrash/tree/workarounds/NavigationView if you want to play around with this workaround, especially on iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternate workaround (actually it is just avoiding possibility of this issue), and as it was tested has no undesirable side-effects. Just for consideration...

The idea is not to remove `DetailsView`, but make it explicitly inactive & hidden. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2 with no crash.

```
struct RootView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var store: AppStore

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ListView()
            .zIndex(store.showingDetails ? 0 : 1)   // << bring to front
        DetailsView()
            .opacity(store.showingDetails ? 1 : 0)  // << hide
            .disabled(!store.showingDetails)        // << deactivate
    }
  }
}
```

No changes in other views.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! However that isn't really going to work for me, since the DetailsView can only be shown when there is a model to show. If there is no model, then the list is shown. I'd have to make the entire view hierarchy below the DetailsView work with an optional model, which would kinda really suck :)

Comment: @KevinRenskers, There was no model in question, but it is of course up to you. At least I've found the solution for myself.

Comment: Yeah true, I didn't want to add even more details and complications in the question. I did solve the problem in the end: I was very close yesterday evening, and finally fixed it this morning. See my answer below. But thanks again for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

In the end the fix that works is to use a custom UIImageView via UIViewRepresentable.

```swift
struct CustomImage: UIViewRepresentable {
  var image: UIImage
  var frame: CGRect

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.image = image

    let view = UIView(frame: frame)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    return view
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
  }
}
```

Which is then used like this:

```swift
GeometryReader { geo in
  CustomImage(image: UIImage(named: "bg")!, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height))
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

See also https://github.com/kevinrenskers/SwiftUICrash/tree/workarounds/CustomImage.

Comment: By my investigation, the crash originated not from the `Image` itself, but of making `NavigationView` internal view full-screen, so if you replace (or use instead) `Image` with, say, `Rectangle` you will get the same crash. Just be aware.

Comment: The weirdest part of it all is that the crash doesn't happen if you press the button in the middle of the screen. It only crashes when you make the switch from a navigation bar button.

Comment: .frame on CustomImage is redundant, remove it.